# Valued permutation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Problem: there are 2 parallel arrays of positive values `A` and `B` of size `n`.

How to find the minimal value for the following target function:

`F(A, B) = Ak + Bk * F(A', B')`

where `A'`, `B'` denote the arrays `A` and `B` with their `k`:th element removed.

I was thinking about dynamic programming approach, but with no success.

How to apply on such kind of problems, where we need to evaluate given function on a permutation?

Comment: May I suggest changing `P1` and `P2` to, for instance, `A` and `B` respectively?

Comment: Yes, `A` and `B` are ok.

Comment: What do you mean by "tail" here?  E.g. does P1' mean P1 without the k-th element?  A short example would be useful.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but are all values in the arrays positive?

Comment: `F(empty, empty) = 0`, and at each frame you picked up an index `k` from arrays and use corresponding elements in the arrays.

Comment: Ok, got it.. there are n! permutations. we are looking for a permutation where the recursive definition with k=1 gives the minimum. the brute force algorithm would calculate all the n!  permutations and evaluate the expression to get the minimum.

Comment: 2yi_H, your understanding is right. Although, we need polynomial solution if such exists. N is about 1000

Comment: Small question, are you looking for the optimal solution, or is an approximate algorithm ok?

Comment: You'll need some heuristic, at least I don't see any better solution than O(n!*evaluation) and that's definitely not feasible for N>15.

Comment: @Fezvez: Yes, I am looking for an optimal polynomial solution.

Comment: @Anton : Sorry for the numerous questions : are there bounds for values of A and B? Do we have anything? (like the problem-solving `A_k>=1` and `B_k>=1`)

Comment: @Fezvez: all values are doubles, `A_i` is about 1000, `B_i` < 1.

Comment: @FezFez It seems that multiplying all the values in B by the reciprocal of the smallest value produces a minimum with the same permutation as the original list, so whether they are greater or less than 1 shouldn't matter. I have not proved this result, though.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: If somebody could prove that there is some property that for two indices i, j with this property, having i before j in the permutation always results in smaller value independent on permutation of the other values, it would be possible to sort based on that property.

Comment: Look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24215/optimization-over-permutation for a quick start. Simulated annealing-like algorithms may be OK for your problem, provided you have good move candidates.

Comment: @Atreys: your statement seems false. (F(A, B) = A2 + B2A1 when n = 2. Changing B1 and B2 changes the minimum)

Comment: @Atreys: Take A = { 2, 3 }, B = { 1, 1 }. Multiplying B by 2 gives optimal permutation (2, 1), multiplying B by 1/2 gives (1, 2).

Comment: @Jan: you're greedy :) Actually I thought about this, if a[i]<a[j] && b[i] < b[j] then pick i before j. But that's only partial ordering.

Comment: @yi_H: Partial ordering will still eliminate many permutations from what needs to be tested.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal solution is to calculate `(B_k - 1)/A_k` and do those with smaller (including more negative) results on the most outside position of the recursion.

This is locally optimal in that you cannot swap a pair of adjacent choices and improve, and therefore globally optimal, since the algorithm gives a unique solution apart from equal values of `(B_k-1)/A_k`, which make no difference. Any other solution which does not have this property is not optimal.

If we compare `A_1+B_1*(A_2+B_2*F)` with `A_2+B_2*(A_1+B_1*F)` then the former will be smaller (or equal) iff

```
A_1 + B_1*(A_2 + B_2*F) <= A_2 + B_2*(A_1 + B_1*F)
A_1 + B_1*A_2 + B_1*B_2*F <= A_2 + B_2*A_1 + B_2*B_1*F
B_1*A_2 - A_2 <= B_2*A_1 - A_1
(B_1 - 1)/A_1 <= (B_2 - 1)/A_2
```

noting `A_k > 0`.

The value of the empty `F(,)` does not matter, as it appears in the end multiplied by all the `B_k`.

Comment: Brilliant. Verified with exhaustive swap search.

Comment: @yi_H: A global optimum must be a local optimum (otherwise it is not optimum).  A local optimum must have this property (otherwise a swap would improve it).  So a global optimum must have this property.  But this property produces a unique solution (up to equality of `(B_k-1)/A_k`) so this must be a global optimum.

Comment: Only true if B_k>=0. counterexample: [7, 9, 4] [0.3, 1.8, -1.4]

Answer (score 2):

**I've come up with a heuristic. Too bad it is not optimal (thanks yi_H!) =(**

At first, I thought that starting with increasing values of `A_i`. However, counterexamples remained (`A={1000, 900}` and `B={0.1, 0.5}`) So I came up with this :

For each value of i in `[1..n]`, compute **`V_i = A_i + B_i*min(A_j) for j!=i`**

Choose i such that `V_i` is the smallest among all the `V` values. Remove `A_i` and `B_i` from A and B. These are the two first terms.

Repeat with `A'` and `B'` until the end (until both are empty).

The algorithm is O(n^2) if you memorize the `V_i` and update them, otherwise it's O(n^3) for a naive implementation.

Edit : Congrats for yi_H for finding counter-examples showing why this is non optimal!

Comment: counterexample: [3, 10, 8] [0.5, 0.3, 0.8], solution should be (0,1,2). please check it, maybe something is wrong with my code but most of the time your algo gives the wrong answer. btw your algo selects the smallest element of `a` as the last term so it cannot be a perfect solution (it isn't so simple)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the same result as you do. `V_0 = 3 + 0.5*8 = 7`. `V_1 = 10 + ... >7`. `V_2 = 8 + ... >7`. So V_0 is the smallest element, and I put 0 as the first element (as your solution). Then I do it again with [10, 8] [0.3, 0.8] : `V_1 = 10+0.3*8 = 12.4`. `V_2 = 8 + 0.8*10 = 16`. V_1<V_2 so 1 is the next element (as your solution). And of course 2 is the last element. I'm not sure I explained clearly my algorithm because I'm pretty sure that the smallest member of A is chosen among the very first.

Comment: Sorry my fault, haven't realised that j depends on i. Please clarify which one to pick if there is two minimal V_i.

Comment: [7, 9, 8] [0.4, 0.2, 0.9] (1,0,2 vs 0,1,2)

Comment: @yi_H : You're totally right! I'll edit my post right away! Thanks for building such counterexamples, I'll see why my intuition failed me so hard!

Comment: Actually your solution seems to be a pretty good starting point for doing incremental refinements, see my anser.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a likely heuristic.  Looking at `F(A, B) = Ak + Bk * F(A', B')` it seems pretty obvious that `F(A', B')` is going to be larger that `Ak` or `Bk`.  Hence, because of the multiplication we should pick `Bk` to be as small as possible, which will give us a value of `k` and hence a possible smallest `F(A, B)` when we calculate it out.  If there is more than one smallest `Bk` we can calculate them all and pick the smallest.

We can then start a brute force algorithm ploughing through all the possible results, but we already have a likely smallest, so we can terminate early if our current trial is going to give us a result larger than we already have.

Comment: *it seems pretty obvious that F(A', B') is going to be larger that Ak or Bk* -- Not with few elements left, as `F([],[]) = 0`.

Comment: Hmm with B_k < 1, I'd rather tend to strive for A_1, ... A_n being an increasing sequence.

Comment: Also since the same permutation is used for both A and B, selecting index so you have small second term might make the first term large. Consider a case of A=(1 100), B=(0.1, 0). Bk as small as possible leads to 100+0*(1 + 0.1*0) = 100, but the other way it's only 1+0.1(100+0*0) = 1 + 10 = 11 (and remember, it was actually said that Bk < 1 by OP)

Comment: @Jan Hudec: It may be that Bk = 0.0 is not allowed.  The initial question says that B only contains "positive" values, which can mean that it cannot be zero.

Comment: @rossum, if you change 0 with 0.0000000000001, this doesn't change Jan's result.

Comment: @Fezvez: agreed, but Jan's argument is better with an allowed value for Bk.

Answer (score 1):

It's not effectively [ O(2^n * n) ] but should works and better than O(n! *n) as in comments

```
int n;
double[n] a,b; //global
double[1<<n] pres; //0's on startup. res is never 0

//Try to calculate this function  if only elements in mask are used.
double res(int mask){
    if(pres[mask]!=0) // do not recalc. it's lazy DP
        return pres[mask];
    if(!mask)
        return pres[mask]=1;  //F(empty) you should replace for your default value
    double pres[mask]=INF; //INF > any result
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        if(mask & (1<<i)){
            //i-th elemnent not used not used 
            pres[mask]=min(min_value,a[k]+b[k]*res(mask-(1<<i));
            //try to delete it recursively and check minimum for all elements
        }
    }
    return pres[mask];
}

double ans=res((1<<n)-1); //get res for all array
```

You can code it without recursion:

```
res[0]=1; //F(empty)
for(int mask=1;mask<1<<n;++mask){
    res[mask]=INF;
    for(int i=0;(1<<i)<=mask;++i){
        if(mask & (1<<i)){
            pres[mask]=min(min_value,a[k]+b[k]*res[mask-(1<<i)];
        }
    }
}
//use res[(1<<n)-1]
```

PS: I use that all elements are positive i.e `a<b && c<d => ac<bd`

Comment: What the hell is this ? Care to explain ?

Comment: @Alexandre, added some comments

Comment: What language is this ? Also, the naive version is not interesting here. What if n = 1000 ?

Comment: it is c-style but really it's pseudo-code. I unserstand that it's works quickly for n<=20-25

Comment: I think it's no more effectively solution in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

I have a loop which tries every combination (N^2) of two element in the list and tries to swap them. If the result (I'm evaluating with k=1) got better, it starts from the beginning.

Seems to be working for N<=10, might be good for larger N as well, but I can't really test because the verifier is the brute force O(N!) algorithm :D Also, I have no idea how fast it converges for large Ns.

Tried randomized algorithm which picks the swap positions randomly and stops after X unsuccessfull tries... it rarely finds the best solution.

**Update**:
Running in python:

```
N=40 N=50 N=60
2.8s 5.3s 8.4s  (starting point: not sorted)
1.7s 2.8s 4.4s  (sort on a first)
1.2s 2.2s 4.3s  (sort on b first)
0.8s 1.9s 2.5s  (using Fezvez's algorithm as a starting point)
```

All measurements contain the running time of pre-sort (the 4th one Fezvez's algorithm). If anybody thinks his solution gets close to the optimal please let me know, I'll test it.

**Update2**:
My algo restared the search after an improvement which was kinda dumb.. I don't want to rerun all test, here is some new data (still can't verify the results, you have to come up with an algorithm which does better..:)) Now with Fezvez+swap improvement:

```
N=100: 1.0s    N=150: 3.1s    N=200: 7.0s
```

Some imporevement stats (N=200, uniform dist.: A: [1, 1000], B: [0.1,0.9])

```
Fezvez     improvemenent
38.172841  36.764499
13.809364  13.805913
27.287438  26.389688
45.101368  40.364930
14.623132  14.599037
33.060609  31.298794
```

Comment: Wow, very impressive work! I was wondering if there could be properties about swapping pairs of values, but I couldn't find any (I wondered if there was a convexity property, i.e for a non-optimal solution, there exists a swap that improves the result. In other words, there are no local minima other than the global minima) But I still guess that it yields pretty good results! Thanks a lot for trying all this stuff!

Comment: @yi_h: I will take up your challenge for a solution which gets close to the optimal.  See my answer which calculates `(B_k-1)/A_k` and then sorts on this result.

Comment: wow, man. seems to be perfect (at least till the precision of floats in python, but I'm pretty sure it's optimal)

Answer (score 0):

*This solution is not optimal, only practical. But I'm afraid this is a hard problem. In the meantime, the following should get you a good permutation.*

Since `b_k < 1`, choosing as the permutation the one which makes the a_k increasing is a good starting point.

You can try [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) from this initial guess. Random transpositions as state transitions should be OK.